# How can I set a global syntax rule that takes precedent over a file specific one?

Tags: vim

I want unexpected characters to have a different background color than the usual ones. I put the following highlighting rule in my `.vimrc`:

```
syntax match NotPrintableAscii "[^\x20-\x7F]"
hi NotPrintableAscii ctermbg=236
```

This words great for some files, but doesn't work with anything that has filetype-specific syntax rules.

Where should I set this so it works with all file types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that this only works sometimes is due to these two things:

- It only matches *toplevel* elements that aren't yet contained in another syntax group. Add `containedin=ALL` to embed this everywhere. Note that this may disrupt the existing syntax.
- The definition in `~/.vimrc` is too early; another syntax script will override yours. Prepend `:autocmd Syntax *` to the `:syntax` command, and place this *after* the `:syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc`.

You need two entries, one for files without filetype-specific syntax rules (e.g. files without an extension) and one for files with syntax rules (e.g. `.py` files):

```
syntax on

" For files that don't have filetype-specific syntax rules
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *syntax match NotPrintableAscii "[^\x20-\x7F]"

" For files that do have filetype-specific syntax rules
autocmd Syntax * syntax match NotPrintableAscii "[^\x20-\x7F]" containedin=ALL

hi NotPrintableAscii ctermbg=236
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by "Prepend `:autocmd Syntax *` to the `:syntax` command"?

Comment: This: `autocmd Syntax * syntax match NotPrintableAscii "[^\x20-\x7F]"`

Comment: For files that don't have filetype-specific syntax rules, I found that things worked well thanks to this answer until I did `:edit`. After doing `:edit`, the syntax was removed. Prefixing `autocmd BufRead * ` to the *non*-autocmd line above fixed this situation for me (i.e., syntax is preserved after `:edit`).